# Error in React native "Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreenNavigationContainer" was not found in the UIManager. "

Tags: javascript, react-native, tensorflow, tensorflow.js, mediapipe

```
This error is located at:
    in RNSScreenNavigationContainer (created by ScreenContainer)
    in ScreenContainer (created by MaybeScreenContainer)       
    in MaybeScreenContainer (created by Drawer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Drawer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AnimatedComponent(View))
    in AnimatedComponent(View)
    in Unknown (created by Drawer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AnimatedComponent(View))
    in AnimatedComponent(View)
    in Unknown (created by PanGestureHandler)
    in PanGestureHandler (created by Drawer)
    in Drawer (created by DrawerViewBase)
    in DrawerViewBase (created by DrawerView)
    in RNGestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (created by DrawerView)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)       
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)     
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by DrawerView)
    in DrawerView (created by DrawerNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)    
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by DrawerNavigator)
    in DrawerNavigator (created by App)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
```

While I was fixing the project from scratch to see where the error was first occurring, I noticed the same error after installing @mediapipe/pose to use tensorflowjs.

```
"@mediapipe/pose": "^0.4.1633558788",
    "@tensorflow-models/pose-detection": "2.0.0",
    "@tensorflow-models/posenet": "2.2.2",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs": "3.7.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native": "0.8.0"
```

This is a version of the Tensorflowjs related packages in package.json.

The first version I installed was @mediapipe/pose@0.5.1675469404.

I tried to clear the cache with "yarn cache clean", and erase "node_modules", and then reinstall using "yarn install", but the same error occurred.

Comment: Have you tried running a ‘pod install’ and rebuilding the app after installing the new packages?

Comment: After installing the @mediapipe/pose package with both iOS and Android available using expo go, an error occurred only on Android.